# Password keeper program does not merge dictionaries as intended

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help with some code id been writing randomly about a passwor keeper

I'd appreciate it so much if the help is beginner friendly.

I tried searching for some ways to merge dicts and the entire app isn't working.

```
User_password_dict = {" " : " "}


def merge_lists(username, password):
    dict_append = {}
    dict_append[username] = password
    User_password_dict.update

def user_info_collection():
    while True:
        username = input (f"What is would you like your'e username to be ?\n\t:")
        if username in User_password_dict:
            print ("you need to change your'e username")
            break
        else:
            password = input(f"Type a password\n\t:")
            password_check = input(f"Type your password again \n\t: ")
            if password_check != password:
                print("you have not input the correct password")
                break
            else:
                User_info = merge_lists(username, password)
                return User_info
                

user_info_collection()
print(User_password_dict)
```

Comment: Just use `user_password[username] = password`, you don't need to do any merging.

Comment: `merge_lists()` doesn't return anything, it modifies `User_password` in place. So you shouldn't assign the result to the variable, that sets the variable to `None`.

Comment: @Barmar,  i believe that you meant `user_password_dict[username] = password` in the notation of the given question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you made a good effort but overcomplicated the `dict` part.

The `merge_lists` function is **not needed** as appending a dict is much simpler than that !!

The key line of code that i added was this:
`user_password_dict[username] = password`

and i removed a couple of unnecessary parts.

So, this will work:

```py
user_password_dict = {}



def user_info_collection():
    while True:
        username = input (f"What is would you like your'e username to be ?\n\t:")
        if username in user_password_dict:
            print ("you need to change your'e username")
            break
        else:
            password = input(f"Type a password\n\t:")
            password_check = input(f"Type your password again \n\t: ")
            if password_check != password:
                print("you have not input the correct password")
                break
            else:
                user_password_dict[username] = password
                return
            
                

user_info_collection()
print(user_password_dict)
```

here is the result:

```
What is would you like your'e username to be ?
        :test
Type a password
        :blah
Type your password again
        : blah
{'test': 'blah'}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I needed it to store the previous ones too but it keeps replacing them. I appreciate the help but sadly, I still have the same problem

Comment: @JosephKizito,  understood - I was providing a solution for the original problem, which is done. So perhaps you might like to open a new question with the modified code where you are struggling (assuming that you are still stuck).